# Modify output on a page created with the View module

Tags: views, 7, hooks, theming

I'm pretty new to Drupal and I'm also pretty sure this is a noob question.

I'm trying to build my theme, and in particular I'm trying to manipulate node output to the page, before using the [View](https://drupal.org/project/views) I simply implemented `myTheme_preprocess_page` hook and got the content doing `$nodes = $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes'];`. From that I made all the needed modification.

Now, I want to order the node using the modification date (or whatever parameter) and the View module seems to do just what I want. The problem is now that in my `preprocess_page` hook I don't have an array of nodes, but all the markup coming from the node.tpl.php file (with missing field of course, because I haven't had the chance to make modification to the output), e.g. insted of `$variables['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes']` I have `$variables['page']['content']['system_main']['main']['#markup']`.

What am I missing? Shouldn't the `preprocess_page` function return the nodes fro the database (as it did without using View) instead of the markup? Is there another hook I don't know about that allows me to do my preprocessing stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access modify date and render data so you can use `hook_views_pre_render(&$view) $view->result` to access result nodes.

and you want to change query condition the you can use `hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)`